# When can we expect Core Java EE Patterns from SUN/Oracle like we already have for J2EE?

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee

Just like we have www.corej2eepatterns.com for J2EE, when can we expect any resource(book) on patterns for Java EE 5/6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This book is for you then: "[Real World Java EE Patterns - Rethinking Best Practices](http://press.adam-bien.com/)"

> This pragmatic book offers the real
>   world knowledge and code you need to
>   develop lean but still maintainable
>   Java EE 5 / 6 applications. Real World
>   Java EE Patterns - Rethinking Best
>   Practices guides you to efficient
>   patterns and best practices in a
>   structured way, with real world code.
>   This book includes coverage of:
>
> 1. An introduction into the core principles and APIs of Java EE 6 (EJB,
>      JPA, JMS, JCA, JTA, Dependency
>      Injection, Convention Over
>      Configuration, Interceptors, REST)
> 2. Principles of transactions, Isolation Levels, Remoting in context
>      of Java EE 6
> 3. **Mapping of the Core J2EE patterns into Java EE**
> 4. Discussion of superfluous patterns and outdated best practices
>      like DAOs, Business Delegates, Data
>      Transfer Objects extensive layering,
>      indirections etc.
> 5. Business layer patterns for domain driven and service oriented
>      architectures
> 6. Patterns for integration of asynchronous, legacy, or incompatible
>      resources
> 7. Infrastructural patterns for eager-starting of services, thread
>      tracking, pre-condition checks, Java
>      EE 6 lookups or integration of
>      third-party Dependency Injection
>      frameworks like Guice
> 8. Hints for efficient documentation and testing
> 9. EJB 2 - EJB 3.X migration
>
>    10. Lean and pragmatic service and domain driven architectures, based on
>          the discussed patterns
>    11. Fully functional Java Connector Architecture (JCA) implementation with
>          source code

Answer (score 0):

You actually can apply those patterns to Java EE or any other collection of enterprise frameworks. [J2EE patterns](http://corej2eepatterns.com/), you mentioned, are just best practices for developing enterprise applications. In general, they do not depend on specific frameworks, like [GoF patterns](http://www.tml.tkk.fi/~pnr/GoF-models/html/) don't depend on specific OO language. So just like GoF patterns are language-agnostic, enterprise patterns are framework-agnostic.

Comment: some patterns from j2ee are obsolute with jee.
for example service locator because of introduction of Context and Dependency Injection in EJB3.
so i need more detail discussion on this topic like which patterns are still usefull and which are obsolute.

Comment: Patterns in "Core J2EE patterns" are to certain extend general purpose and framework-agnostic, but not completely. Some patterns are outdated for JEE. A book that is really framework agnostic is "Patterns of Enterprise Application".